# How to check which compiler im using in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm using Windows. I have installed Visual C# 2010, mono and MonoDevelop. I know that MonoDevelop can use either Microsoft's compiler or mono's compiler. How do I check which compiler is used by MonoDevelop? And how do I change it to other one?

Comment: Change the project's settings.  if you are using any mono libs then you have to use mono, as .net framework does not include those, likewise mono does not support the .net namespaces.  Seeems odd you have mono installed and don't know seem to know if you even need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see and change the active runtime for the current solution using the *Project->Active Runtime* menu, or the active configuration picker in the toolbar. These options will be invisible if you do not have any alternate runtimes installed.

Note that these two places to set it are slightly inconsistent - the toolbar differentiates between using the "Default" runtime, and using that same runtime explicitly. You can specify the default runtime in the MonoDevelop global options: *Preferences->.NET Runtimes*.

And of course, if you want to double-check, you can just look at the build output section in the Errors Pad and see what compiler it's invoking.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, depending on which .NET frameworks you have installed, you can check the *Runtime* section at *Help -> Info -> Details* to see which version of the .NET framework MonoDevelop is running on. This seems to impact which .NET compiler is used if you select *Microsoft .NET*.

I am still figuring out how to change the framework version used, e.g. in order to use features of C# 6 in your project if you have .NET 4.0 installed as well. See [the Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40776/unable-to-build-under-mono-on-windows) for a discussion on that topic. I will update this answer once the topic is resolved.